# SQLServer SQL query with a row counter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL query, that returns a set of rows:

```
SELECT id, name FROM users where group = 2
```

I need to also include a column that has an incrementing integer value, so the first row needs to have a 1 in the counter column, the second a 2, the third a 3 etc

The query shown here is just a simplified example, in reality the query could be arbitrarily complex, with several joins and nested queries.

I know this could be achieved using a temporary table with an autonumber field, but is there a way of doing it within the query itself ?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

For starters, something along the lines of:

```
SELECT my_first_column, my_second_column,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY my_order_column) AS Row_Counter
FROM my_table
```

However, it's important to note that the `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ...)` construct only determines the values of `Row_Counter`, it doesn't guarantee the ordering of the results.

Unless the `SELECT` itself has an explicit `ORDER BY` clause, the results could be returned in any order, dependent on how SQL Server decides to optimise the query. ([See this article for more info](http://blogs.msdn.com/queryoptteam/archive/2006/05/02/588731.aspx).)

The only way to guarantee that the results will *always* be returned in `Row_Counter` order is to apply exactly the same ordering to both the `SELECT` and the `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT my_first_column, my_second_column,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY my_order_column) AS Row_Counter
FROM my_table
ORDER BY my_order_column  -- exact copy of the ordering used for Row_Counter
```

The above pattern will always return results in the correct order and works well for simple queries, but what about an "arbitrarily complex" query with perhaps dozens of expressions in the `ORDER BY` clause? In those situations I prefer something like this instead:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM
(
    SELECT my_first_column, my_second_column,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ...) AS Row_Counter  -- complex ordering
    FROM my_table
) AS t
ORDER BY t.Row_Counter
```

Using a nested query means that there's no need to duplicate the complicated `ORDER BY` clause, which means less clutter and easier maintenance. The outer `ORDER BY t.Row_Counter` also makes the intent of the query much clearer to your fellow developers.

Comment: Why the nested query ? With my quick testing of ROW_NUMBER() the resulting query ended up sorted by the row counter value anyway.

Comment: The nested query above is unnecessary, but occasionally it can be useful to write "SELECT t.* FROM (...) as t WHERE t.Row_Counter BEWEEN 20 and 30" as an efficient way to page data.

Comment: The nested query *is* required if you want to guarantee that the resultset will always be returned in Row_Counter order for "arbitrarily complex" queries. (See http://blogs.msdn.com/queryoptteam/archive/2006/05/02/588731.aspx for more info.)

Comment: The extra "ORDER BY" clause inside the nested query is a bit pointless though - I've edited the SQL to comment it out.

Comment: Note that if you use the PARTITION BY feature, the ROW_NUMBER will reset as expected, and so in the general case the outer ORDER BY may need to also include the columns from the PARTITION BY

Comment: Is there a way to do the same in SQL2000? ROW_NUMBER() is only supported from 2005

Answer (score 11):

In SQL Server 2005 and up, you can use the [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function, which has options for the sort order and the groups over which the counts are done (and reset).

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way is to use a variable row counter. However it would be two actual SQL commands. One to set the variable, and then the query as follows:

```
SET @n=0;
SELECT @n:=@n+1, a.* FROM tablename a
```

Your query can be as complex as you like with joins etc. I usually make this a stored procedure. You can have all kinds of fun with the variable, even use it to calculate against field values. The key is the `:=`

Comment: You are correct, I am sorry. This is only for MYSQL. In TSQL you have to use Row_Number()

Answer (score -2):

Heres a different approach. 
If you have several tables of data that are not joinable, or you for some reason dont want to count all the rows at the same time but you still want them to be part off the same rowcount, you can create a table that does the job for you.

Example:

```
create table #test (
        rowcounter int identity,
        invoicenumber varchar(30)
        )

insert into #test(invoicenumber) select [column] from [Table1]

insert into #test(invoicenumber) select [column] from [Table2]

insert into #test(invoicenumber) select [column] from [Table3]

select * from #test

drop table #test
```

Comment: I specifically stated in the original question that I knew it could be done with a temporary table, but was looking for a solution that avoided that.