# SELECT TOP N with variable

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following data in a SQL table

Temp table variable `@RndQuesnCount` contains this data,

```
Recid conceptID MinDisplayCount
1      3839     2
2      4802     3
```

Question table : `QuesTable`

```
 QuesCompID     Ques_ConceptDtlID
  88         4802
  89         4802
  90         4802
  91         4802
  92         4802
  93         4802
```

What I would like to show is the min display count for question which is in `@RndQuesnCount` for the concept id, so now the data should come as below

```
  QuesCompID    Ques_ConceptDtlID
  88         4802
  89         4802
  90         4802
```

because `conceptid` (4802) has min display count 3 in `@RndQuesnCount` table.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simple use of `ROW_NUMBER()` and a join gets the results, I think. Data setup:

```
declare @RndQuesnCount table (recid int,conceptid int,mindisplaycount int)
insert into @RndQuesnCount(Recid,conceptID,MinDisplayCount) values
(1,      3839,     2),
(2,      4802,     3)

declare @QuesTable table (QuesCompID int,Ques_ConceptDtlID int)
insert into @QuesTable(QuesCompID,Ques_ConceptDtlID) values
(88,         4802),
(89,         4802),
(90,         4802),
(91,         4802),
(92,         4802),
(93,         4802)
```

Query:

```
select
    t.rn,
    t.QuesCompID,
    t.Ques_ConceptDtlID 
from
    @RndQuesnCount rqc
        inner join
    (select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Ques_ConceptDtlID ORDER BY QuesCompID) rn from @QuesTable) t
        on
            rqc.conceptID = t.Ques_ConceptDtlID and
            rqc.MinDisplayCount >= t.rn
```

Results:

```
rn                   QuesCompID  Ques_ConceptDtlID
-------------------- ----------- -----------------
1                    88          4802
2                    89          4802
3                    90          4802
```

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
declare @RndQuesnCount int;

select @RndQuesnCount=MinDisplayCount 
from table_variable where conceptID=4802;

set rowcount @RndQuesnCount;

select * from QuesTable;
```

Comment: no hardcoded value, i need to get the values from the column name

Comment: I have edit my answer to get @RndQuesnCount value dynamically from table_variable.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
 ;WITH  cte as
     (  select *,row_number() over(order by QuesCompID) as row_num
        from   QuesTable   
        join   @RndQuesnCount
        on     Ques_ConceptDtlID=conceptID)
 SELECT QuesCompID,Ques_ConceptDtlID  
 FROM   cte 
 WHERE  row_num<=MinDisplayCount
```

**Result:**

```
QuesCompID    Ques_ConceptDtlID
88               4802
89               4802
90               4802
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add counter column to query result and get rows only with counter that less or equal to MinDisplayCount.

[SQLServer SQL query with a row counter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492679/sqlserver-sql-query-with-a-row-counter)